# アプリの最新版へのアップデートテスト

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

App Storeにてリリース済みのアプリのバージョンアップにて、アプリが最新版かどうかチェックして最新版でなければアップデートを促す機能を追加する予定です。

現在この機能の実機テストをしており（一時的にアプリのVersionを下げてテストしています）、ストアに遷移してアップデート完了するところまで確認したいと思っています。

AppStoreの遷移まではうまくいくことが確認できたのですが、インストールボタンを押しても正常にアップデートされません。
.ipaを作成して試してもみたのですがこちらもうまくいきませんでした。

実機ビルドしたアプリはストアのものでアップデートできない原因等ありますでしょうか。

追記(2020/1/20):

> インストールボタンを押しても正常にアップデートされません。

上記ですが、ボタンを押してもアップデートの進捗が動かず、AppStoreを閉じて対象のアプリをタップしても一時的にひらけない状態となります。
その後アプリを一旦Killしてもう一度開くと、アップデートボタンを押す前の状態に戻ります。
アプリの署名がXcodeからのビルドとストアのもので異なるのが原因かもしれません。

Comment: 「インストールボタンを押しても正常にアップデートされません。」の部分をもう少し詳しく書いたほうがいいかも。App Store 上でどの様に表示されるのか。ボタンを押したあとどのような状態になるのかなど。

Comment: SAWAさま　ありがとうございます。詳細を追記致しました。

Comment: アプリをアップデートする時には、そのアプリのプロセスは強制終了させられます。なにがアプリの終了を妨げているのでしょう。手元のアプリで試してみた限りでは「Xcodeからアプリを起動→AppStore or SKStoreProductViewController で公開バージョンを再インストール」で正常にアプリが強制終了され公開バージョンのアプリがインストールされました。

Comment: TestFlightからアプリをインストールした場合も試してみてはいかがでしょうか？ この場合なら公開アプリと同じ署名になるはずです。（アプリ実行中に手動でAppStoreを開いてクラウドから再インストール）

Comment: SAWAさま　ご教示ありがとうございます。TestFlightからのインストールを試してみます。